# changing the content of a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to change the content of a div. I have three divs:

```
 <div
      class="box1"
      style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red"
    >
      A
    </div>
    <br />
    <div
      class="box2"
      style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: blue"
    >
      <label for="">tex</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div
      class="box3"
      style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: yellow"
    >
      C
    </div>
```

when the page is ready the 2 and 3rd box displays none:

```
function hideElementBoxOnLoad() {
  let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
  let box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
  let box3 = document.querySelector(".box3");

  box2.style.display = "none";
  box3.style.display = "none";
}

$(document).ready(hideElementBoxOnLoad);
```

I want a click that toggles the content of box2 and box3 into box1 and then back to box1 content:

```
function changeContent() {
  let chang = true;
  let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
  let box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
  let box3 = document.querySelector(".box3");

  let box2Content = box2.textContent;
  let box3Content = box3.textContent;

  if (chang) {
    box1.textContent = box2Content;
    chang = !chang;
    if ((box1.textContent === box2Content)) {
      box1.textContent = box3Content;
    }
  }
}

let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeContent);
```

So far it worked but it does not display the content of box2 only box3. what did i do wrong and what better way can i toggle with a boolean.

Comment: `if (chang)` will always be true, with `let chang = true` at the start of your function.

Comment: Instead of trying to move the content from one div to another you could probably just make the button click iterate over the array of them and set one of them to active at a time.

Comment: `if ((box1.textContent = box2Content))` - that is an assignment, not a comparison. But even as a comparison, what would be the point? You explicitly set `box1.textContent = box2Content` two lines before.

Comment: @CBroe the point is just to check if the present content of the div is box2 , if it is box2 then change to box3...

Comment: But you're checking after you assign it, it can't change in between.

Comment: Perhaps you're forgetting that javascript is *single-threaded*.  If your code says "x = y; if (x==y)` then it will *always* be true.   No other code is given the opportunity to "jump in" and change it (including the use interacting with the input/clicking).

Comment: "toggles the content of box2 and box3 into box1 *and then back to box1 content*" - then you do not want to use `box1.textContent = box2Content` because that will lose box1content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below

Instead of trying to swap content between each div just use JS to go through the array of them and swap an active class between them;

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        var change = document.getElementById('change');
        var counter = 0;

        change.addEventListener('click', function(){   
            boxes[counter].classList.remove('active');
            boxes[counter].nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
            counter++;

            if(counter === boxes.length) {
                counter = 0;
                boxes[0].classList.add('active');
            }
        });
```

```css
.box {
            display: none;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .box.active {
            display:block
        }
```

```html
<div class="box active">A</div>
        <div class="box">B</div>
        <div class="box">C</div>

        <button id="change">Change Content</button>
```

Comment: why did you increase the counter++?

Comment: @dave The counter is incremented to essentially track the button clicks compared to the array and add and remove the class from the previous one so that it loops through from C back to A. I can modify the snippet if you just want it to go A B C then stop at C

Comment: If you *really* wanted to get rid of `counter` then you could get the current `.active` element instead.  The `counter` is useful here and clear, but if you have a number of these, you don't want `counter1`, `counter2` variables, so not very module

Comment: I think I get it now, after the first click the active class is already on the second div with 'boxes[counter].nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');' so then on the second click 'counter++'  its now box[1]  then the operation repeats itself until it get to the length of the array(getElementsByClassName) and returns to default

Comment: @dave Correct. The counter is just there to match the spot in the array so it knows to go back to A once it is at C.

Answer (score 1):

im not completely sure if i understood ur question.
but below u can see and even test with the snippet button.

the button now add what ever content in in the yellow box, and whats in the input field of the blue box into the red box. listing them downwards.

if you want to replace the content completely.

just change the logic to `box1.innerHTML += spacer+box3.innerHTML+spacer+input.value`

this is the most simple way to do it thats easy to understand just by reading the code i think.

hope this helps!

```js
function changeContent() {
    //the button
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    //the boxes
    const box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
    const box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
    const box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
    //a spacer
    const spacer = "<br>";
    //the input field
    const input = document.getElementById("input");

    //logic
    box1.innerHTML += spacer+box3.innerHTML+spacer+input.value
}
```

```css
div{
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#box1{
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 73, 73);
}
#box2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
}
#box3 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

button{
    padding: 3px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
     <div id="box1">
         <p>contetnt A</p>
     </div>
     <br />
     <div id="box2" >
         <label for="">tex</label>
         <input id="input" type="text" />
         <button id="btn" onclick="changeContent()">click me</button>
     </div>
     <br />
     <div id="box3">
         contetnt C
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

List of bugs :-

1. You had declared the var `chang` locally instead of globally, which make it true whenever you runs the function.
2. You are directly writing value from one tag to another, which causing the data loss, when you run your function second time.

For example :- When you click the button first time, the data is swapped, but for the second click, the data first **div** is lost and cannot be brought back...

**Solution** :- Store the data in an array in `document.ready` event handler and extract data from the array to update you html tags.

```js
function hideElementBoxOnLoad() {
  let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
  let box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
  let box3 = document.querySelector(".box3");

  box2.style.display = "none";
  box3.style.display = "none";

  content = [box1.textContent, box2.textContent, box3.textContent];

  let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", changeContent);
}

var content = [];
window.onload = (hideElementBoxOnLoad);

var index = 0;

function changeContent() {
  let chang = true;
  let box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
  /*  let box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
    let box3 = document.querySelector(".box3");
    let box2Content = box2.textContent;
    let box3Content = box3.textContent;
    if (chang) {
      box1.textContent = box2Content;
      chang = !chang;
      if ((box1.textContent === box2Content)) {
        box1.textContent = box3Content;
      }
    }
   */

  function cycle(n, x = 0, y = content.length - 1, a = 1) {
    n += a;
    if (n > y) return x;
    if (n < x) return y;
    return n;
  }

  index = cycle(index);
  box1.textContent = content[index];

}
```

```html
<div class="box1" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red">
  A
</div>
<br />
<div class="box2" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: blue">
  <label for="">tex</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<br />
<div class="box3" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: yellow">
  C
</div>

<button id="btn"> CLICK ME </button>
```

**Explaination**

Here I first stored the tags `textContent` in a array `content`, in the starting of the code.

Then, inside the button click handler, a simple `cycle` function to cycle on the values stored inside the `content` array.

Comment: can you explain further when u meant i should store the data into an array in document.ready:  let data = [box1Content, box2Content, box3Content];
$(document).ready(data);